# Loading cached pages with different content in WindowsRT Store App

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to enable caching for a page that loads when an ListView item is clicked. So when the user clicks a second time on the same item, the app will navigate to the previous cached page.
(I'm using LayoutAwarePages and I suspect that this should be possible if in the OnNavigatedTo method the NavigationMode parameter is different from NavigationMode.New)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You affect the page caching by setting the [NavigationCacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode.aspx) property of the page in its constructor. By default it is disabled, but if you enable it, you'll get the existing page instance every time you navigate to it.  This means that even if the user navigates to a different item in your ListView, the same instance of the page will be reused.

I've found a [library](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Page) reimplementing the navigation framework to make it more like the one in Windows Phone, i.e.:

- When navigating back the cached page is used.
- When navigating forward a new instance of the page is created.

If I understand your question correctly, you require a different caching behavior from both of the above. To achieve that you could either base your alternative navigation framework on the one in the library I linked to or simulate the behavior by persisting just the page state for each item instead of actually caching the pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the NavigationCacheMode property isn't for much use in this case indeed and the library caches the last page but not every page for every item that is clicked...